# Javascript or Jquery : change CSS of an attribute of an id selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code :

```
<span id="sn1">
<a href="javascript:removeEtape(2);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a>
<a id="aUn1" href="javascript:upEtape(1,0);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></a>
<a id="aDn1" href="javascript:downEtape(1,2);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></a>
my text here<br></span>
```

I need change color of "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" after I have selected id "aUn1".

I try this but, it doesn't works :

```
$('#aUn1').attr('[class$="glyphicon-chevron-up"]').css('color', 'grey');
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `class` to the `selector`.

```
$('#aUn1.glyphicon-chevron-up').css('color', 'grey');
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your code like this

```
$(".glyphicon-chevron-up").css('color', 'grey');
```

Comment: Now you got a syntax error and the answer is technically wrong too. ;)